# Linking a static library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker

When using a third-party library in your project while you have to code, sometimes the source has the following directory pattern.

```
[dir]........Third Party Project
  [file]       project.vcxproj
  [file]       et cetera
  [dir]........lib
  [dir]........lib64
    [file]        project.lib
  [dir]........source
    [file]        header1.cpp
    [file]        header1.h
    [file]        header2.cpp
    [file]        header2.h
```

The sources files are next to the header files.

Adding header and lib directories as needed:

```
`$(ProjectDir)/source/`
```

respectively

```
`$(ProjectDir)/lib64/`
```

Using #pragma comment to link to the library.

No problem there. But what happens when start building the application. Is it linking to the library or does it build the two files `header1.cpp` and `header2.cpp`?

Comment: Are you hesitant to build and check what will happen?

Comment: It builds fine, just don't know if it would be better to copy the header into a seperate directory.

Comment: @Ruijter Keeping header files in separate directory is one of the best practices even though it is not mandatory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding directories to your INCLUDE and LIB path does not influence what actually gets compiled, just the places where it finds headers and libs.

Unless you actually add header1.cpp and header2.cpp to your project source file list, it won't get compiled.

Comment: Reviewing myself, this goes for a shared library too?

Comment: @Ruijter For shared libraries in native c++ / MSVC you link to the import library not the dll. I used the word native to mean not .NET /CLR.